# shortest ruby equivalent of this Python Snippet

Tags: python, ruby, string

I'm looking for the shortest ruby equivalent of this Python snippet

```
a, b, c, d = map(int, raw_input().split(" "))
```

is there anything shorter than this?

```
a, b, c, d = gets.split(" ").map &:to_i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without argument, [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) split the string on whitespaces (`$;`):

```
"1 2 3 4\n".split
# => ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

In other word, you don't need to call `chomp` to remove trailing newline:

```
a, b, c, d = gets.split.map &:to_i
```

---

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) of Python is similar (no need to specify argument):

```
>>> "1 2 3 4\n".split()
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value for the `split` pattern is `$;`, and the default value for `$;` is `nil`. A pattern of `nil` means "split on whitespace", which is not 100% equivalent to what you have (which is "split on a single space character"), but if you can live with that, then you can shorten your expression to:

```
a, b, c, d = gets.split.map &:to_i
```